# Problems with special characters with Jabref on Windows when using the DOI to BibTeX feature

Tags: jabref

I use JabRef on Windows 7 64 bit. The option for the .bib-file is set to UTF8. When I use the *DOI to BibTeX* feature in Jabref and import any DOI that leads to a source with special characters in its properties, say this one ...

```
10.1007/978-3-540-92788-4_1
```

### Windows

... I get this result on Windows (version 2.9):

[image]

... it's the same with 2.10 beta3 on Windows:

[image]

... and the same for the final release for 2.10 for the doi `10.1051/jp2:1995145`:

[image]

Here is a screenshot of the saved file opened in Notepad++:

[image]

### Linux

It is working on Linux (Xubuntu 13.10 with version 2.10 beta):

[image]

### Options

Here are my options, which are equal for both installations (imported the options file into the other installation):

[image]

However I'd like to stay with utf-8-encoded files and try not to rework the faulty entries. Is there some way to have the .bib-file in utf-8 and still use the DOI to BibTeX feature? It's a bit odd JabRef can load the .bib-file which is already encoded in utf-8 but when I add something, it produces the faulty parts.

The thing is, whether I open a .bib-file saved by JabRef on either Windows or Linux, Notepad++ says (in the lower right) it is encoded **Ansi as UTF-8** so I'm quite confused what is actually causing this if there aren't any encoding issues.

Comment: Have you modified the preview window at all?

Comment: No, I think although I don't fully understand your question. Well I don't recall any modifications in regards to the preview windows. Installed JabRef about 3 days ago and played around with it, just changed some settings in regards to the owner, Biblatex and set that encoding option to UTF8. Hope that answers your question.

Comment: It looks to me as if the file got saved in a non-UTF8 format to start with, so the chars are messed up. I'd fix in a text editor, make sure JabRef is correctly set to use UTF-8 then re-open the fixed file.

Comment: Hm... I wish. I did that and it didn't solve it. I opened my .bib file in Notepad++, converted it from *UTF-8 without BOM* to *UTF-8* and the re-opened it with JabRef. Still the same problem. I then opened a new file in JabRef on both Windows and Linux just for that DOI and on Windows it lead to screenshot taken in Notepad++. So I think there is more to it.

Comment: I am going to uninstall JabRef completely now (via CCleaner) and then check my %user folder for leftovers and then install it again.

Comment: Damnit nothing changed. This makes JabRef on Windows pretty useless. :(

Comment: As far as I know, one has trouble compiling .tex files  that are encoded in UTF8 format with BOM, at least for (PDF)LaTEX. For .bib files and Biber I'm unsure, but I think it would be safer to save them without BOM.

Comment: Huh? Hm... I don't think so. Tested some example file via `file -i test.bib` on Xubuntu and it gave me `charset=utf-8` which clearly indicated an utf-8 encoding, so I don't think all the users on Linux have major problems unless "utf-8" on Xubuntu stands actually for utf-8 without BOM.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior. Adding the two mentioned DOIs using the Web Search (F5) -> DOI to BibTeX will results in broken umlauts. The bib file encoding was set to UTF8, versions tested was 2.10. You should just file a bug report in the JabRef bug tracker.

Comment: I'd agree with @matth here: an issue with the importer rather than the general JabRef program. (I use it routinely with UTF-8 entries but type them in myself.)

Comment: To whoever added the bug already, thank you. I was just in the process of signing up to Sourceforge but [apparently someone got to it faster.](http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/bugs/1213/) :)

Comment: There has always been an issue with the Win version of Jabref regarding importing, encoding and Java if special characters involved. For the quick fix, I have tried several different text editors (e.g TextPad) till I get the correct solution. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since Jabref [relies on the standard Java's Preferences API](http://sourceforge.net/p/jabref/mailman/jabref-users/thread/8a363cdc0607250132i7d6b8fb4g970c465e55022037@mail.gmail.com/), it assumes the encoding of the stuff being imported is the same as the host OS's. So we critically need an additional option to specify that encoding on windows. A tentative solution is explicitly [call Jabref's jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394616/running-jar-file-in-windows) and [set encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding) from the command line as

```
java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" JabRef-2.10.jar
```

To make `java` work you may have to [set the `PATH` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1672281/environment-variables-for-java-installation).